# share data from service to component after render the function in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

i have service, in service, I have a "cohortTabsResult" method whitch sets the charts array. i want to use this arry in "chart.component"

```
export class CohortService {
 public charts: Array<any>;

 cohortTabsResult(obj){
    this.charts = []
    const subscription = this.cohortDataReq(obj).subscribe(res => {
        if(res.status !== 500){

            const dataObj = {
                definedChart: obj.graph_type,
                definedChartData: []     
            };
            this.charts.push(dataObj);
            const response = res.json() 
            //console.log(response)

            if (response.error) {
                //this.isLoaded = false;                              
            } 
            else{
                 Array.prototype.forEach.call(response.data, dataRes => {
                    const newData = this.getChartDataFormat(dataRes, obj.graph_type, "userType")
                    dataObj.definedChartData = _.cloneDeep(newData);
                  });

            } 

        }

    });

}
```

}

and this is my chart.component here I am getting the empty array.

```
export class ChartCohortComponent implements OnInit{
  charts: any;
  constructor(private cohortService: CohortService, private route: 
  Router, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
       this.charts = this.cohortService.charts;
  }


  ngOnInit(){ 

    console.log("ch", this.charts)

  }
 }
```

Comment: At what point do you run the `cohortTabsResult` function to populate the `charts` array? That is not in the code.

Answer (score 0):

import CohortService to your component, add it to the providers in @component, now you can access the variables inside the service. :D

```
import { CohortService } from '../../cohort.services'; // whatever the path is.. 
@Component({
  selector: '',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
  providers: [CohortService]
})
export class ChartCohortComponent implements OnInit{
  charts: any;
  constructor(private cohortService: CohortService, private route: 
  Router, public activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
       this.charts = this.cohortService.charts;
  }


  ngOnInit(){ 

    console.log("ch", this.charts)

  }
 }
```

Comment: It will not work, because puting  it in the provider array of the component will produce a new instance of the service, so the charts value will not be set. He can just inject the service in the component constructor.

Comment: @GeoAstronaute:you can inject in the app.module.ts.

Comment: Yes, In his example it is obviously the case, because he is already using the service in an another one. So re-providing it in the component will not work and leads to the creation of a new instance. So he just have to use it in his component.